# How do I print methods of a class

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I have searched and cannot find an answer.

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def description(self):
        print self.name
        print self.age

hippo = Animal('Alex', 12)
hippo.description
```

So my issue is that I cannot figure out how to call description my instance of Animal. All I get is `None` returned but it will not print the name and age. I have tried multiple things but all have the same result

Comment: Have you tried `hippo.description()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke the method by putting `()` after it:

```
hippo.description()
```

See below:

```
>>> class Animal(object):
...     def __init__(self, name, age):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
...     def description(self):
...         print self.name
...         print self.age
...
>>> hippo = Animal('Alex', 12)
>>> hippo.description()
Alex
12
>>>
```

Comment: That solved my issue! Thanks! I can't believe that is the one thing I didn't try. Especially since that is something I should have known. I just got confused because I could print hippo.name. But that is because name is an attribute of hippo, right? And since description is a method then it must be called?

Comment: It must be called? Have you ever read a basic Python tutorial?

Comment: Do you know what a "method" or "function" is?

Comment: Yes I am aware what functions are. However I am just now learning about classes and the OO part of python. I got confused about methods and attributes and was overlooking simple stuff. Sorry for the question. Obviously asking questions makes people stupid and mistakes are simply not allowed.

Comment: @EvolutionXJ - No, ignore him.  Your question is fine.  In fact, in some languages, you don't need the `()` to invoke a method.  And yes, the reason you could print `hippo.name` was that it is an attribute, not a method.  `description` on the other hand is a method and must be invoked.